# Digitizing and converting PDF to shapefile using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, georeferencing, pdf

Is there a way to convert the pdf to shapefile in QGIS?

I have plenty of PDF files (I think they are exported from AutoCAD) and I need to georeference them and convert them to shapefile. It would be easier if I do it automatically (Not digitize everything by hand at least), since we have plenty of files.

Comment: Conversion depends on the content of your PDF files.

Comment: @BERA Yes I did drag and drop in qgis, also convert it from gdal to raster, but it is not georeferenced

Comment: @Erik The content of the PDF file is buldings, pipelines, the logo and etc...

Comment: If the PDFs are indeed exported from CAD, easiest way would be to ask the provider for the DWG/DXF files.

Comment: You might search on pdf to shapefile or variations thereon.  There is software that claims they can do it.  I assume that if your features are not stored as vectors in your pdfs but as parts of a raster, you will not be able to use these converters.  In that case you could try the GDAL-Raster Conversion-Polygonize(raster to vector) tool but the success of that hinges in part on having shared pixel values for each different set features and distinct ones between features..

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the PDF was created and how complicated are the features there (as someone already said, you could ask provider for the original format - DWG, etc.), but if it is only general image (can be PDF, JPG,..) with few line features, you can add it to QGIS and then georeference it using tool **Georeferencer** (find it in Tab Raster --> Georeferencer).

You can use for example Google basemap and indentify (by clicking at the specific point in PDF you've imported into Georeferencer and then using option From Map Canvas) at least four points at corners. Then go to Georeferencer Settings, use method, click Run and the PDF will be exactly at the place you want it.

Unfortunately then you have to create new layer and re-draw features from PDF manually. It in not the fastest and funniest solution, but I think that's the only thing you can do with PDG or JPG.

[image]

Comment: From the question it should be assumed that those are vector files, so assuming raster images is most probably out of scope